# Webstorm: Memorized getter trickers warning about "read-only property"

Tags: javascript, webstorm

**Background**

When I use a [memorized getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) like this:

```
var myModule = {

    get foo () {
        delete this.foo;
        return this.foo = 'something'
    }
};
```

in Webstorm I receive the warning:

> Property is read-only

**Question**

Why do I get this warning and can I make it disappear?

Comment: It probably does not take into account that you are deleting the property first. Not sure how to make it not show the warning though.

Comment: Interesting way to define a lazy fire-once getter. Never seen that before - If webstorm gets confused, people reading your code will get confused aither (so did I at first). Maybe you could just use plain old "private" members to hold state.

Comment: Webstorm does static analysis on the code - this one would require dynamic analysis I think

Comment: Actually the memorized getter is not used for reasons of being "private", but to control the time when a value is assigned to a property in connection with testing. Certain properties involves calls to external, async operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm seems to show the warning because assignments to accessor properties without a setter are ignored in non-strict mode and throw in strict mode.

And that could be a problem indeed, in case you want to change the value of `foo` but the getter has not been called yet.

Therefore, a better practice could be defining a setter too

```
var myModule = {
  set foo (val) {
    delete this.foo;
    this.foo = val;
  },
  get foo () {
    delete this.foo;
    return this.foo = 'something';
  }
};
```

Then WebStorm should recognize the setter and thus not show the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can supress WebStorm's introspection like this:

```
var myModule = {
    get foo () {
        delete this.foo;
        //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
        return this.foo = 'something'
    }
};
```

But I think this is a bad practice to do so, and you should avoid doing this unless you really have to.

How did I find it out? WebStorm has a neat lightblub containing useful suggestions for nearly all warnings and errors by <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Tamas Hegedus. You answer was helpful and I would have preferred to also check mark this one. Unfortunately I have to choose only one and the other answer contained both the "why" and the "how to fix". So it seems most fair to check mark that one even though I am divided in relation to which method to use to fix the problem.